# Минимальное значение SQL

Tags: sql

Необходимо выбрать минимальное значение из поля, но если окажется что оно равно 0 то нужно взять следующее значение... Т.е. если простая выборка возвращает например числа 13, 34, 5, 0, 89 - мне нужно получить 5, а если простая выборка возвращает все строки в которых только нули то тогда нужно возвратить 0...

Спасибо

Comment: а написать условие `where val > 0` проблематично?

Comment: диалект СУБД укажите еще в тэгах

Answer (score 4):

```
COALESCE(MIN(CASE WHEN val != 0 THEN val END), 0)
```

Comment: Если вместо нуля при отсутствии иных устроит Null, то COALESCE можно убрать.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT IF(t.min_res = 0 AND t.max_res = 0, 0, t.res) FROM
(SELECT MIN(a.value) AS min_res, 
    MAX(a.value) AS max_res,
    MIN(b.value) AS res 
 FROM `table` a
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `value` <> 0) AS b ON b.`value`
) t;
```

`value` здесь - имя вашего столбца, `table` - имя вашей таблицы